# sinon - create stub that returns own arguments

Tags: node.js, sinon, stub

How can I make a stub that returns it's own arguments, like so:

```
var stub = sinon.stub().returns(???);

var result = stub('foo'); //result = foo
```

This will be nested so I can't return nothing and then check stub.getCall...

Answer (score 13):

Try this

```js
stub.returnsArg(0);
```

See [docs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/#stubreturnsargindex)

Comment: The [doc for v2](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v2/) has moved.

Answer (score 3):

Modify your code like below:

```
- var stub = sinon.stub().returns(???);
+ var stub = sinon.stub().returnsArg(0);

var result = stub('foo'); //result = foo
```

Comment: this answer is identical to the one above, which was made a year earlier